# Why cant I use shake listener in ontouch event?

Tags: android, accelerometer

I have a problem when I am running my android app.
The shake listener cannot be called when I touch down.
My logic is "Send message when I am shaking and touch down button at the same time. But it seems that cannot work for my listener part.
But the android studio cant tell me where is the error or code wrongly.

Here is my button code.

```
shakeitBtn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int action = event.getAction();
            switch (action) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Shake!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    mShakeDetector = new ShakeDetector(new ShakeDetector.OnShakeListener() {

                        public void onShake() {
                            Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                            v.vibrate(300);
                            status = RELEASE_TO_SEND;
                        }
                    });
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    if (status == RELEASE_TO_CANCEL) {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Shake canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        if (status == RELEASE_TO_SEND) {
                            DatabaseReference childRoot = rootRoomName.push();
                            Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                            map.put("name", userName);
                            map.put("message", "I AM BUSY!!!".toString());
                            childRoot.updateChildren(map);
                        }
                        else{}
                    }
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    if (event.getY() < 0) {
                        status = RELEASE_TO_CANCEL;
                    } else {
                    }

                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
    chat_room.super.onResume();
    mSensorManager.registerListener(mShakeDetector, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
}

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(mShakeDetector);
    chat_room.super.onPause();
}
```

Here is my share detector code

```
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;

public class ShakeDetector implements SensorEventListener {

// Minimum acceleration needed to count as a shake movement
private static final int MIN_SHAKE_ACCELERATION = 5;

// Minimum number of movements to register a shake
private static final int MIN_MOVEMENTS = 2;

// Maximum time (in milliseconds) for the whole shake to occur
private static final int MAX_SHAKE_DURATION = 500;

// Arrays to store gravity and linear acceleration values
private float[] mGravity = {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f};
private float[] mLinearAcceleration = {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f};

// Indexes for x, y, and z values
private static final int X = 0;
private static final int Y = 1;
private static final int Z = 2;

// OnShakeListener that will be notified when the shake is detected
private OnShakeListener mShakeListener;

// Start time for the shake detection
long startTime = 0;

// Counter for shake movements
int moveCount = 0;

// Constructor that sets the shake listener
public ShakeDetector(OnShakeListener shakeListener) {
    mShakeListener = shakeListener;
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    // This method will be called when the accelerometer detects a change.

    // Call a helper method that wraps code from the Android developer site
    setCurrentAcceleration(event);

    // Get the max linear acceleration in any direction
    float maxLinearAcceleration = getMaxCurrentLinearAcceleration();

    // Check if the acceleration is greater than our minimum threshold
    if (maxLinearAcceleration > MIN_SHAKE_ACCELERATION) {
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

        // Set the startTime if it was reset to zero
        if (startTime == 0) {
            startTime = now;
        }

        long elapsedTime = now - startTime;

        // Check if we're still in the shake window we defined
        if (elapsedTime > MAX_SHAKE_DURATION) {
            // Too much time has passed. Start over!
            resetShakeDetection();
        } else {
            // Keep track of all the movements
            moveCount++;

            // Check if enough movements have been made to qualify as a shake
            if (moveCount > MIN_MOVEMENTS) {
                // It's a shake! Notify the listener.
                mShakeListener.onShake();

                // Reset for the next one!
                resetShakeDetection();
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    // Intentionally blank
}

private void setCurrentAcceleration(SensorEvent event) {
    /*
     *  BEGIN SECTION from Android developer site. This code accounts for
     *  gravity using a high-pass filter
     */

    // alpha is calculated as t / (t + dT)
    // with t, the low-pass filter's time-constant
    // and dT, the event delivery rate

    final float alpha = 0.8f;

    // Gravity components of x, y, and z acceleration
    mGravity[X] = alpha * mGravity[X] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[X];
    mGravity[Y] = alpha * mGravity[Y] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[Y];
    mGravity[Z] = alpha * mGravity[Z] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[Z];

    // Linear acceleration along the x, y, and z axes (gravity effects removed)
    mLinearAcceleration[X] = event.values[X] - mGravity[X];
    mLinearAcceleration[Y] = event.values[Y] - mGravity[Y];
    mLinearAcceleration[Z] = event.values[Z] - mGravity[Z];

    /*
     *  END SECTION from Android developer site
     */
}

private float getMaxCurrentLinearAcceleration() {
    // Start by setting the value to the x value
    float maxLinearAcceleration = mLinearAcceleration[X];

    // Check if the y value is greater
    if (mLinearAcceleration[Y] > maxLinearAcceleration) {
        maxLinearAcceleration = mLinearAcceleration[Y];
    }

    // Check if the z value is greater
    if (mLinearAcceleration[Z] > maxLinearAcceleration) {
        maxLinearAcceleration = mLinearAcceleration[Z];
    }

    // Return the greatest value
    return maxLinearAcceleration;
}

private void resetShakeDetection() {
    startTime = 0;
    moveCount = 0;
}

// (I'd normally put this definition in it's own .java file)
public interface OnShakeListener {
    public void onShake();
}
}
```

Comment: Does ShakeDetector work without the onTouch()?

Comment: It can work. I have tried to put shake part out of button and it can send out message. However, it doesn't work when I put the codes back into button part.

Answer (score 0):

As you said the ShakeDetector works if you start it before the `onTouch()` I suggest the following:

1) Create a parameter in your Activity/Fragment:

```
bool vibrateOnShake = false;
```

2) Init your ShakeDetector outside the onTouch():

```
mShakeDetector = new ShakeDetector(new ShakeDetector.OnShakeListener() {
    public void onShake() {
        if (vibrateOnShake) {
            Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            v.vibrate(300);
            status = RELEASE_TO_SEND;
        }
    }
});
```

3) Update your onTouch():

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();

    switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            vibrateOnShake = true;
            ...
            break;
        ...
    }
}
```